# Ansible windows update module how to install ALL updates

Tags: windows-update, ansible

Is there a way to use the `win_updates` module in ansible to install ALL updates without having to specify every update category manually on the playbook?

Answer (score 1):

taken from https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_updates_module.html#examples :

```
- name: Install all updates and reboot as many times as needed
  ansible.windows.win_updates:
    category_names: '*'
    reboot: yes
```

Comment: Umm, but as it states, it does not install those? Does it install them if the `state: installed` is removed?

Comment: citing the official docs:

state

    Choices:
    installed ←
    searched
    downloaded

Controls whether found updates are downloaded or installed or listed
This module also supports Ansible check mode, which has the same effect as setting state=searched


so installed means updates get installed - I fixed the comment to be less confusing.

Comment: The following```- name: Check again for updates
      tags: updates
      win_updates:
        reboot: yes
        state: installed```
returns
```ok: [172.16.16.31] => {"changed": false, "filtered_updates": {"8fcc22f5-a4cc-49d9-8187-ce647e5f22c7": {"categories": ["Definition Updates", "Microsoft Defender Antivirus"], "filtered_reason": "category_names", "id": yadayadaydada"found_update_count": 0, "installed_update_count": 0, "reboot_required": false, "updates": {}}
```
I think that this means that ansible filtered update and did not install it? This is supposed o install all?

Comment: example above in no longer the case to update all packages - therefore I'll update the example - from the ofic. docs provided by the link in the answer